# Does Kotlin have method-CALL labels?

Tags: kotlin, self-documenting-code

I'm moving from Swift to Kotlin, and loving it so far. However, I'm used to declaring methods like this (pretend the referenced methods exist and work):

```Swift
// Swift method declaration
func drawCircle(inRect rect: CGRect, antialiased: Bool) {
    super.antialiased = antialiased
    super.drawCircle(inRect: rect)
}
```

and calling them like this:

```Swift
drawCircle(inRect:myRect, antialiased: false)
```

which is beautifully self-documenting and reads like English. However, in Kotlin, a similar method like this:

```Kotlin
fun drawCircle(inRect: Rectangle, antialiased: Boolean) {
    super.antialiased = antialiased
    super.drawCircle(inRect)
}
```

which already starts to sound odd using a variable named `inRect`. But then it gets worse when I call it:

```Kotlin
drawCircle(myRect, false)
```

and here we see the biggest problem: One can likely guess by reading this line alone that `myRect` is a rectangle in which the circle will be drawn. However, what is `true`? It could be antialiasing, yes, but it could also be whether to draw it opaquely, or some toggle about whether to draw it at all! Anyway, I could cite more reasons why Swift and Objective-C programmers love their labels with method calls, but I've made my point.

**Is there any way to enable labels on method *call* in Kotlin?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no compiler option to force this syntax, but you can still use it in your code, see the docs: [Named arguments](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#named-arguments).

To say it short, the syntax for your function is

```
drawCircle(inRect = myRect, antialiased = false)
```

You can even change function arguments order in a call using named arguments.

```
drawCircle(antialiased = false, inRect = myRect)
```

The limitations are:

- You cannot call Java methods with this syntax because Java bytecode does not always preserve parameter names;
- Mixing positioned (unnamed) and named arguments is limited: all the named arguments should go after the positioned ones:

  ```
  fun f(x: Int, y: Int, z: Int) = 0

  f(x = 0, y = 0, z = 0) // OK
  f(0, y = 0, z = 0) // OK
  f(0, z = 0, y = 0) // OK
  f(x = 0, 0, 0) // Error
  ```